# Restarting a command in Discord using c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, restart, discord

So I know this seems stupid, but I've tried to restart a method after a set time interval for my bot. I got the timer down along with a good majority of the code. However I am having trouble restarting the method after its done. I have also tried using return; instead of calling Restart, but that didn't work for me either. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
private void RegiseterAutoBleachCommand()
    {

        commands.CreateCommand("bleach")
            .Do(async (e) =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                int randomBleachIndex = rand.Next(bestBleach.Length);
                string bleachToPost = bestBleach[randomBleachIndex];
                await e.Channel.SendFile(bleachToPost);



                Restart();

            });
    }

    private void Restart()
    {
         RegiseterAutoBleachCommand();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So after looking for other questions like this for an answer. I came along the while command and got this to loop.

```
    private void RegiseterAutoBleachCommand()
{

    commands.CreateCommand("bleach")
        .Do(async (e) =>
        {

            while (true)
           {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            int randomBleachIndex = rand.Next(bestBleach.Length);
            string bleachToPost = bestBleach[randomBleachIndex];
            await e.Channel.SendFile(bleachToPost);

               }

        });
}
```